# Promise.all response

Tags: javascript, promise

Can I add `Promise.resolve(value)` and `Promise.reject(error)` at response of `Promise.all()`.

For example,

```
function transferFRQ(fromUserId, fromCompanyDetails, toUserDetails, toCompanyDetails,) {
  return Promise.all([
    transferRFQCompany(fromCompanyDetails, toCompanyDetails),
    replaceRFQCreatedBy(fromUserId, toUserDetails)
  ])
    .then(result => Promise.resolve(result))
    .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
}

function transferRFQCompany (fromCompanyDetails, toCompanyDetails) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Request.updateMany({
      "company.id": fromCompanyDetails._id
    }, {
      $set: {
        company: {
          id: toCompanyDetails._id,
          name: toCompanyDetails.name,
          logo: toCompanyDetails.logo
        }
      }
    }).then(result => resolve(result))
      .catch(error => reject(error));
  });
}

function replaceRFQCreatedBy (fromUserId, toUserDetails) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Request.updateMany({
      "createdBy.id": fromUserId
    }, {
      $set: {
        createdBy: {
          id: toUserDetails._id,
          firstName: toUserDetails.firstMame,
          lastName: toUserDetails.lastName
        }
      }
    }).then(result => resolve(result))
      .catch(error => reject(error));
  });
}
```

I don't know whether is it correct or not, but what I need is to handle the response of `transferRFQ` properly because I will need to add `transferRFQ` in another `Promise.all()` to handle the error properly.

**Am I doing in the wrong way? if so, How to do it correctly**

Any additional advice is welcome!

Comment: yes you are doing it the wrong way. `Request.updateMany` already returns a promise, and then you are wrapping it in another promise. you should just `return Request.updateMany...` instead

Comment: So, simple `return result ` and `return error` will solve the problem. are you sure about that?

Comment: on `transferFRQ`, no need to wrap it in another promise, since `Promise.all` already returns a promise, reduce the complexity there

Comment: no, i mean you handle the result where you used `transferFRQ`

Comment: Does it return promise or text?

Comment: here, take a look at this example https://gist.github.com/shierro/d14b1de029237ae2a67265439e930a70

Comment: does it make sense @ali Razmjo? let me know how you go

Comment: please check your github

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177932/discussion-between-theo-and-ali-razmjo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice that you should not use **unnecessary Promise wrappers**, & avoid **javascript hoisting**.

You should try to do something like this instead

```
// Note that this is declared before used, to avoid javascript hoisting
function transferRFQCompany (fromCompanyDetails, toCompanyDetails) {
    return Request.updateMany({ // updateMany already returns a promise right? no need to wrap it in another promise
      "company.id": fromCompanyDetails._id
    }, {
      $set: {
        company: {
          id: toCompanyDetails._id,
          name: toCompanyDetails.name,
          logo: toCompanyDetails.logo
        }
      }
    })
  });
}

// Note that this is declared before used, to avoid javascript hoisting
function replaceRFQCreatedBy (fromUserId, toUserDetails) {
  return Request.updateMany({ // updateMany already returns a promise right? no need to wrap it in another promise
    "createdBy.id": fromUserId
  }, {
    $set: {
      createdBy: {
        id: toUserDetails._id,
        firstName: toUserDetails.firstMame,
        lastName: toUserDetails.lastName
      }
    }
  })
}

function transferFRQ(fromUserId, fromCompanyDetails, toUserDetails, toCompanyDetails,) {
  return Promise.all([
    transferRFQCompany(fromCompanyDetails, toCompanyDetails),
    replaceRFQCreatedBy(fromUserId, toUserDetails)
  ])
}
// Sample usage async/await style
(async () => {
  try {
      // put your params, of course
      const result = await transferFRQ(...params); 
      // `result` is result of .then()
  } catch (e) {
    // `e` is result of .catch()
  }

  // or use it in promise-style
  transferFRQ(...params)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error)
})()
```